# BrowserSync doesn't work with angular's views

Tags: angularjs, browser-sync

I just installed / ran BrowserSync for my angular project:

```
browser-sync start --server --files "*"
```

It is now listening to any changes in my main index.html file as well as in css/app.css but refuses to work with anything beyond that. For example, I want it to work with my templates (templates/*.html) & controllers (controllers/*.js).

p.s. if I run

```
browser-sync start --server --files "templates/*.html"
```

it works fine with my templates but obviously wont work with anything else outside this directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in an array of paths to watch like this below:

```
browser-sync start --server --files "controllers/*.js, templates/*.html"
```

Currently there is no work around apart from this.

Answer (score 4):

To watch all files in directories without specifying each folder, use

`browser-sync start --server --files "**/*.*"`